# "solve a riddle involving a fish and a rake" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> If ...., I then have to **solve a riddle involving a fish and a rake**.

What is the meaning of **solve a riddle involving a fish and a rake** in the above sentence?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: I know riddle meaning, fish meaning, don't know rake, and don't understand the whole phrase altogether

Comment: You should do a dictionary search for "rake". You should also provide the source of the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how dictionaries define the word *rake*: a rake is a gardening tool that consists of a pole with a toothed crossbar or fine tines at the end, used especially for drawing together cut grass or smoothing loose soil or gravel. Here's a picture of it:

[image]

The phrase *to involve something* means to have or include something as a necessary or integral part or result. Once again, I got all that information straight from a dictionary.

Finally, this is what that sentence fragment is saying:

> I then have to solve a riddle (a puzzle) that includes (incorporates, contains, consists of) two things: a fish (the kind of fish that swims in water) and a rake.

I think that's as simple as you can possibly break this down.